# How to display other sites content in our sites with out using iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to display other sites content in our sites with out using iframe?
Is it possible to load one sites file details in our site with out using the iframe.

Comment: I hope you've got permission from the other site to do so.  Displaying their content without permission is possibly illegal and definitely immoral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [PHP Curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) library.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and quite easy with **[YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)**.

> The Yahoo! Query Language is an
>   expressive SQL-like language that lets
>   you query, filter, and join data
>   across Web services. With YQL,
>   developers can access and shape data
>   across the Internet through one simple
>   language, eliminating the need to
>   learn how to call different APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Ajax due to the Same Origin policy. There are two ways to circumvent this.

- Use a proxy - As Gazler said, you can create a proxy script in PHP to download the file. Call the file proxy script from your javascript.
- Use JSONP - You can use JSONP for [cross domain communication](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/). Make sure you read the cautionary note

Comment: Any idea why this was down voted? I would like to know what was wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with the code below. Two notes though:

1) I'm not sure this works with IE

2) Heed the advice put out by @Paul_Tomblin and @Codemwnci about getting permission to display a different site's content.

The html part is:

```
<object id="external-page" type="text/html" data="" > 

</object>
```

The javascript part in jquery is:

```
$("#external-page").attr("data", "http://foreign-site.net/foreign-page.html");
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I have achieve this in the past is as follows

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("http://someurl", "rb");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);

echo "<div>Your Content</div>";
echo "<div>";
print($contents);
echo "</div>";
echo "<div>More of your contents";

?>
```

Comment: Please be careful when using this code though. As @PaulTomblin has pointed out, using content without permission is stealing. At least using frames, it gives the calling site a chance to use javascript to prevent it.

Comment: Why not just using file_get_contents on the url, turns 3 lines into 1.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery should be able to do this (I'm assuming you're using jQuery since you've tagged the question with it). You should look at the documentation on the [.load() method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) as that has an excellent example in there

**Edit:** As Nick points out below, this will only work for pages on the originating site due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in javascript

Comment: You can't use `.load()` here, check out the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which prevents this for security reasons :)

Comment: @Nick Craver Oops, you're totally right. Thanks for pointing this out, editing my answer to reflect this